# How to list values of multiple columns of the same table and count how many times these values are repeated for each column in mysql?

Tags: mysql, count, sum, union

i have these data table

```
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| format1 | format2 | format3 | format4 |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|       1 |       1 |       3 |       4 |
|       1 |       2 |       3 |       7 |
|       1 |       1 |       3 |       7 |
|       1 |       2 |       2 |       3 |
|       2 |       1 |       7 |       1 |
|       2 |       2 |       7 |      34 |
|     ... |     ... |     ... |     ... |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

and i need a query that represents the next scheme: put the unique (distinct) values of the whole data table in the first column and count how much times they are repeated for each format, like this:

```
+---------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|  format | f1  count | f2  count | f3  count | f4  count |
+---------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|       1 |         4 |         3 |      null |         1 |
|       2 |         2 |         3 |         1 |      null |
|       3 |      null |      null |         3 |         1 |
|       4 |      null |      null |      null |         1 |
|       7 |      null |      null |         2 |         2 |
|      34 |      null |      null |      null |         1 |
|     ... |       ... |       ... |       ... |       ... |
+---------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

The first column represent the distinct list (order by ASC) of all numbers inserted into all the table columns retrieved with this query

```
SELECT distinct format1 AS val
FROM table
UNION
SELECT distinct format2 AS val
FROM table
UNION
SELECT distinct format3 AS val
FROM table
UNION
SELECT distinct format4 AS val
FROM table
ORDER BY  val ASC
```

Each column (first excluded) is the count of the times that the number appears for the corresponding format.

I unsuccessfully tried to combine many SELECT query (it depends on how many formats there are).

How to combine them all?

Comment: Is this a homework problem? If so, it's ridiculous.

Comment: yes it is ... you have the solution?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple... reframe the problem...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,format_type INT NOT NULL
,value INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table (format_type,value) VALUES
(1,     1), 
(1,     1), 
(1,     1), 
(1,     1), 
(1,     2), 
(1,     2), 
(2,     1), 
(2,     2), 
(2,     1), 
(2,     2), 
(2,     1), 
(2,     2), 
(3,     3), 
(3,     3), 
(3,     3), 
(3,     2), 
(3,     7), 
(3,     7), 
(4,     4), 
(4,     7), 
(4,     7), 
(4,     3), 
(4,     1), 
(4,    34);

SELECT * FROM my_table;
+----+-------------+-------+
| id | format_type | value |
+----+-------------+-------+
|  1 |           1 |     1 |
|  2 |           1 |     1 |
|  3 |           1 |     1 |
|  4 |           1 |     1 |
|  5 |           1 |     2 |
|  6 |           1 |     2 |
|  7 |           2 |     1 |
|  8 |           2 |     2 |
|  9 |           2 |     1 |
| 10 |           2 |     2 |
| 11 |           2 |     1 |
| 12 |           2 |     2 |
| 13 |           3 |     3 |
| 14 |           3 |     3 |
| 15 |           3 |     3 |
| 16 |           3 |     2 |
| 17 |           3 |     7 |
| 18 |           3 |     7 |
| 19 |           4 |     4 |
| 20 |           4 |     7 |
| 21 |           4 |     7 |
| 22 |           4 |     3 |
| 23 |           4 |     1 |
| 24 |           4 |    34 |
+----+-------------+-------+

SELECT format_type,value,COUNT(*) FROM my_table GROUP BY format_type,value;
+-------------+-------+----------+
| format_type | value | COUNT(*) |
+-------------+-------+----------+
|           1 |     1 |        4 |
|           1 |     2 |        2 |
|           2 |     1 |        3 |
|           2 |     2 |        3 |
|           3 |     2 |        1 |
|           3 |     3 |        3 |
|           3 |     7 |        2 |
|           4 |     1 |        1 |
|           4 |     3 |        1 |
|           4 |     4 |        1 |
|           4 |     7 |        2 |
|           4 |    34 |        1 |
+-------------+-------+----------+
```

The rest of the problem - dealing with missing values and formatting would best be handled in the presentation layer/application-level code, assuming you have that.